# Does this case fit the definition of a replay attack?

Tags: attacks, terminology

I read the definition of a replay attack on Wikipedia. However I don't know if the following case fits the description:
An attacker captures a HTTP request sent to a web server, modifies the request parameters and sends the request to the web server.

Is this a replay attack even if the request sent is not the same as the original?

Answer (score 1):

A replay attack is sending the same packet more than once. Ie: charging your visa 10 times or resending authentication from a different source. What you describe is session hijacking or more specifically "sidejacking".

Comment: Just to be clear, in this case, the attacker doesn't MITM the victim. The first request sent by the victim reaches the web server however the attacker was able to capture it